# How to prevent riverpod's ConsumerWidget rebuilds managing ThemeMode

Tags: dart, riverpod, themedata

I'm managing the ThemeMode of my flutter application with Riverpod state Provider that works as expected up until I try to read `Theme.of(context)` to get ThemeData's current values which causes rebuilding of the widget in excess (13~14 times in a row). So I decided create a provider for ThemeData following Riverpod's [repository example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/stackoverflow/lib/common.dart) but I'm still getting these unecessary rebuilds. How can I prevent these unnecessary riverpod rebuilds to get ThemeData? and why is it happening?

This code is available on [github](https://github.com/rsegecin/rivertheme).

main app:

```
final themeProvider = Provider<ThemeData>(
  (ref) => throw UnimplementedError(),
  dependencies: const [],
);

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()));
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeMode themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider);

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("building app");
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: FlexThemeData.light(scheme: FlexScheme.mandyRed),
      darkTheme: FlexThemeData.dark(scheme: FlexScheme.mandyRed),
      themeMode: themeMode,
      builder: (context, child) {
        final theme = Theme.of(context);
        return ProviderScope(
          overrides: [
            themeProvider.overrideWithValue(theme),
          ],
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

ThemeMode Provider:

```
@riverpod
class ThemeModeState extends _$ThemeModeState {
  @override
  ThemeMode build() {
    return ThemeMode.dark;
  }

  static ThemeMode getSystemTheme(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeMode mode = ThemeMode.system;
    if (mode == ThemeMode.system) {
      if (MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.light) {
        mode = ThemeMode.light;
      } else {
        mode = ThemeMode.dark;
      }
    }
    return mode;
  }

  void toggleThemeMode() {
    if (state == ThemeMode.dark) {
      state = ThemeMode.light;
    } else {
      state = ThemeMode.dark;
    }
  }
}
```

homescreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  static String routeName = "home";

  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeData themeData = ref.watch(themeProvider);
    final TextStyle headlineMedium = themeData.textTheme.headlineLarge!;

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("building home");
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello World",
              style: headlineMedium,
            ),
            SwitchListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              title: const Text('Theme mode'),
              value: ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider) == ThemeMode.light,
              onChanged: (value) {
                ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider.notifier).toggleThemeMode();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd get rid of that override.  Overrides are primarily intended for testing, and get abused too often in places that don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am attaching a shorter code to reproduce this problem (without using generation):

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final themeProvider = Provider<ThemeData>(
  (ref) => throw UnimplementedError(),
  dependencies: const [],
);

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MainApp()));
}

class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeMode themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider);
    print("#building app");

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      themeMode: themeMode,
      builder: (context, child) {
        print("##building builder");
        final theme = Theme.of(context);
        return ProviderScope(
          overrides: [themeProvider.overrideWithValue(theme)],
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeData themeData = ref.watch(themeProvider);
    print("###building home");

    return Scaffold(
      body: SwitchListTile(
        title: const Text('Theme mode'),
        value: ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider) == ThemeMode.light,
        onChanged: (value) {
          ref.read(themeModeStateProvider.notifier).toggleThemeMode();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

final themeModeStateProvider =
    AutoDisposeNotifierProvider<ThemeModeState, ThemeMode>(
  ThemeModeState.new,
);

class ThemeModeState extends AutoDisposeNotifier<ThemeMode> {
  @override
  ThemeMode build() => ThemeMode.dark;

  void toggleThemeMode() {
    if (state == ThemeMode.dark) {
      state = ThemeMode.light;
    } else {
      state = ThemeMode.dark;
    }
  }
}
```

**By the way,** don't use `ref.watch` in widget lifecycle management methods and callbacks. Use `ref.read` instead:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  ref.read(themeModeStateProvider.notifier).toggleThemeMode();
},
```

---

Your problem lies in the `MainApp` widget, specifically in the `builder` parameter. The short solution to the problem is to not use `of(context)` inside `builder`, and it looks like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeMode themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider);

    final theme = themeMode == ThemeMode.light 
      ? ThemeData.light() 
      : ThemeData.dark();

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme,
      darkTheme: theme,
      themeMode: themeMode,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return ProviderScope(
          overrides: [themeProvider.overrideWithValue(theme)],
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
```

Now your rebuilds are optimized.

Speaking for the future, most likely your `ThemeData` should also have a full-fledged `NotifierProvider` and inside the `build` method elegantly `watch` to the current `themeModeStateProvider`. Then the `ProviderScope -> overrideWithValue` construct is not useful at all.

Well, the long solution is to write an issue to the flutter repository.

---

**The final version**, taking into account `Localizations`, will look like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final ThemeMode themeMode = ref.watch(themeModeStateProvider);
    final ThemeData themeLight =
        FlexThemeData.light(scheme: FlexScheme.mandyRed);
    final ThemeData themeDark = FlexThemeData.dark(scheme: FlexScheme.mandyRed);
    final ThemeData themeData = (themeMode == ThemeMode.light)
        ? localizeThemeData(context, themeLight)
        : localizeThemeData(context, themeDark);
        
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: themeLight,
      darkTheme: themeDark,
      themeMode: themeMode,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return ProviderScope(
          overrides: [themeProvider.overrideWithValue(themeData)],
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );

  static ThemeData localizeThemeData(BuildContext context, ThemeData themeData) {
    final MaterialLocalizations? localizations =
        Localizations.of<MaterialLocalizations>(context, MaterialLocalizations);
    final ScriptCategory category =
        localizations?.scriptCategory ?? ScriptCategory.englishLike;
    return ThemeData.localize(
        themeData, themeData.typography.geometryThemeFor(category));
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ruble thank you for your reply. I've compiled your proposition with `AutoDisposeNotifier` and also replaced `ref.watch` with `ref.read` on the switch's trigger and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: yes, because i made your code shorter to try to localize the problem. So far I have not found a solution to the problem

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin check i added the solution

Comment: I agree the problem it's using `of(context)` inside the builder or even inside the HomeScreen widget. I even mentioned it in a comment to Randal's answer. I tried to workaround this issue with the same approach you're proposing, but there's something MaterialApp does with themeData that differs from `Theme.of(context)`. With the system's default Theme I don't know if you could notice the difference. If I find how to mimic what MaterialApp does with themeData I post it here.

Comment: `Theme.of(context)` applies some localization features to the themedata that changes text size some other things. I've committed [here](https://github.com/rsegecin/rivertheme/blob/main/lib/main.dart) these change if you want to add them to your post I'd be happy to mark as an answer.

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin added code based on your comments

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to listen to the whole Theme in your application. You want widgets to listen to only what they use.

Since you converted the Theme to a *Provider*, you can use Riverpod's "select" feature:

TL;DR, instead of:

```dart
final ThemeData themeData = ref.watch(themeProvider);
final TextStyle headlineMedium = themeData.textTheme.headlineLarge!;
```

Do:

```dart
final TextStyle headlineMedium = ref.watch(
  themeProvider.select((themeData) => themeData.textTheme.headlineLarge!,
);
```

This way, your consumer will listen only to `headlineMedium` instead of the whole theme.

Comment: Thank you for you reply Remi. That's interesting I've added it in the code but I'm still getting rebuilds, would `ProviderScope` being declared twice in the widget tree be an issue? It's being added in the runApp line and MaterialApp builder otherwise I wouldn't be able to listen to themeModeStateProvider and override themeProvider initial value.

Comment: My answer shows how to filter rebuilds cause by `ref.watch`. It could be that your widget is rebuilding due to something else entirely, such as the widget's parent rebuilding

Comment: I bet the culprit of these excessive rebuilds is the MaterialApp animation, when I use `Theme.of(context)` somehow it triggers them. There's a property on Material App that you can change the animation when you switch app's theme mode and it correlates directly the amount of rebuilds I'm getting. I guess I won't be fixing this problem but rather stick with a workaround.

Comment: The animation that occurs on Theme change is definitely triggering widget rebuild in-between frames and I saw it [here](https://youtu.be/BJtQ0dfI-RA?t=4332) that even if I added a condition I wouldn't stop listening. Btw thank you very much by these amazing tools you developed and shared with the community.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.light` triggers on ANY change to MediaQuery, including things like screen size (rotation?).  You'll want to use the new `MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf` to only trigger on changes to that parameter specifically.

Comment: hi Randal, thank you for your response. The code section you've mentioned I left there by mistake for a subsequent question I was going to make this section actually it's not being executed when the error occurs I'm sorry about it.  Although I know that the error occurs in a similar fashion with `Theme.of(context)` if I don't use it the code runs perfectly but I can't access the theme without running with the rebuilding problem.